# Receive files on a REST web service using a POST request

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to get files making a POST request to an action. The web service is working fine but I can't retrieve that file "as it is". Cake automatically transfoms the $this->request->data into an array and that's not what I need. I need to save that file into a BLOB column in my db.

Please help me!!!

Thanks in advance for you help!!

this is my controller code, I'm on CakePHP 2.1.0:

```
class TransfersController extends AppController {
public $name = 'Transfers'; 
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function record($rfc = null, $numop = null, $source = null) {        
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (strlen($rfc) > 0) {             
            if ($numop > 0) {
                $this->loadModel('Client');
                $client = $this->Client->findByRfc($rfc);
                if (!empty($client)) {
                   if ($client['Client']['enabled'] == 1) {
                        // unknown way to get the received file                         

                        $this->Transfer->set('client_id', $client['Client']['id']);                             
                        $this->Transfer->set('num_operacion', $numop);
                        $this->Transfer->set('source', $source);
                        // $this->Transfer->set('xml', $this->request->data);
                        if ($this->Transfer->save($this->request->data)) {
                            //$message = 'Ok';
                            $message = $data;
                        } else {
                            $message = 'No se pudo registrar la transmisión';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $message = 'Su cuenta ha sido suspendida. Póngase en contacto con nostros para resolver éste inconveniente.';
                    }
                } else {
                    $message = 'El RFC ' . $rfc . ' no está registrado';
                }
            } else {
                $message = 'El número de operación no es válido';
            }
        } else {
            $message = 'El RFC no es válido';
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'La petición es inválida';
    }
    $this->set('message', $message);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to save the request array into the DB? what do you men by  -"I need to save that file .." ??

Comment: I want to save the file as binary data, not the array. The action "record" would allow to "upload" a file to the database via web service

Answer (score 1):

For those who have the same question, I could work with the received file using:

```
$this->request->input();
```